# angularjs: Form entry problems

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have this dynamic form which entries I would like to save. The problem is that the saved entry is like this `[{"name":"Noora","":{"Gender":"Woman","Address":"filler address"}}]` I'm curios why the app saves the info after name like a nameless list. Name is hardcoded input and the other two (Gender and Address) can be dynamically added when using the program.

Here is the form entry html part:

```html
<form>
  <h2>Sign in:</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="eventInput">Name</label>
    <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="eventInput" data-ng-model="newEntry.name">
  </div>
  <div data-ng-repeat="field in event.fields">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="{{$index + 1}}">{{field.name}}</label>
      <input style="width: 200px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="{{$index + 1}}"  data-ng-model="newEntry.[field.name]">
    </div>
  </div>
<span>{{entries}}</span>
  <div class='wrapper text-center'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <button style="width: 100px;" data-ng-click="addEntry()" class="btn btn-primary">Enroll</button>
        <p></p>
        <button style="width: 100px;" data-ng-click="back()" class="btn btn-primary">Back</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is the controller:

```js
 App.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, eventService) {

   $scope.event = eventService.getCustomers()[$routeParams.id];

   $scope.back = function() {
     $location.path('/');
   };
   $scope.addEntry = function() {
     $location.path('/');
     $scope.event.entries.push($scope.newEntry);
   };
 });
```

I would like to either be able to name the child list or just record the entries into a continuous list. Any idea how would it be possible?

Br,
Norri

Comment: change `newEntry.[field.name]` to newEntry[field.name] & check

Comment: Ah what a silly mistake! Thank you! You saved me a lot of time.